# Help with Razor for a beginning programmer

Tags: c#, .net, razor

Hi I have the following sample razor script> now I need to extend this and add an if statement after the @foreach (DataRow row in Dnn.ReportResults().Rows) with an if statement to check if the querystytring value foo is the same as the value of the column with name foo if this is correct that tne row can be rendered

```
<table>
<thead>
@{var table = Dnn.ReportResults();}
<tr>
 @foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
 {
 <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
 }
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 @foreach (DataRow row in Dnn.ReportResults().Rows)
 {
 <tr>
 @foreach (var value in row.ItemArray)
 {
 <td>@value</td>
 }
</tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

thanks for the help

Comment: various tries with if request.querystring["foo"] i coudl get it to work in a normal c# asp.net app. I think I just need to see it in a razor setup i must have misplaced a } or an @

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<tbody>
 @foreach (DataRow row in Dnn.ReportResults().Rows)
 {
    if(Request.QueryString["foo"] == "bar")
    {
        <tr>
        @foreach (var value in row.ItemArray)
        {
            <td>@value</td>
        }
        </tr>
    }
}
</tbody>
```

I've found that if you've got a razor syntax error the YSD that is produced is usually very helpful, especially for things like too many @s

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table> 
    <thead> 
    @{var table = Dnn.ReportResults();}
<tr>
    @foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    {  <th>@col.ColumnName
        </th>  }
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (DataColumn col in table.columns)
    {
        if (col.ColumnNamn == Request.QueryString["foo"])
        {
    foreach (DataRow row in Dnn.ReportResults().Rows)
    {  <tr>
        @foreach (var value in row.ItemArray)
        {  <td>@value
            </td>  
        }
    </tr>
    }
        }
    }
</tbody>
```