# Controller side list object in a view Bag. then on html side step through with foreach to produce tables

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, list, foreach, c#-3.0

I have a list that has many objects in it. I want to step through it and for each object i want to create a row. Basically I want a table made. Can anyone please help  me.

```
           List<Event> events = parseResponse.Deserialize<List<Event>>(_responseAsString);
           ViewBag.eventss = events;
```

html

how do i stepp through it and  create rows or a table thank you

this information below is many objects thats in my "event" list
           "[{\"event_key\":\"cc2a1802-2b04-4530-ad50-0d4f0ed19dd3\",\"user_token\":\"40e62a11-40c4-408d-8cdd-1293cbaf9a41\",\"event_set_key\":\"615017f2-ae28-4b8d-9def-cf043642b928\",\"event_type\":\"Arrival\",\"event_date\":\"6/20/2011 4:15:28 PM\",\"event_amount\":\"100\",\"event_location_key\":\"50fc1c22-d77b-4a91-b31d-da036827060b\",\"event_location_name\":\"Store2\",\"event_location_city\":\"Pittsburgh\",\"event_location_state\":\"PA\",\"event_location_country\":\"US\",\"event_location_lat\":\"\",\"event_location_long\":\"\",\"event_description\":\"\",\"event_acknowledged\":\"True\"},{\"event_key\":\"2ac9e25e-137c-4a72-8cc5-157d67ea66c1\",\"user_token\":\"58cb4fcd-e140-4232-88c9-06eecb95b63d\",\"event_set_key\":\"00710ca7-f5d7-4c7a-bbfb-95491ae278ef\",\"event_type\":\"Arrival\",\"event_date\":\"9/23/2011 4:15:28 PM\",\"event_amount\":\"45\",\"event_location_key\":\"5a732dd5-9459-4cdd-a980-f3daf1a07343\",\"event_location_name\":\"Store4\",\"event_location_city\":\"Pittsburgh\",\"event_location_state\":\"PA\",\"event_location_country\":\"US\",\"event_location_lat\":\"\",\"event_location_long\":\"\",\"event_description\":\"\",\"event_acknowledged\":\"False\"},{\"event_key\":\"386b1fa1-11b2-48d9-b7f1-4bbe21ced487\",\"user_token\":\"c3d8b7ff-d85f-42a8-98f6-e091b48c2280\",\"event_set_key\":\"dc55843b-f8cf-4e8a-9091-188ce0609fe1\",\"event_type\":\"Arrival\",\"event_date\":\"9/18/2011 4:15:28 PM\",\"event_amount\":\"100\",\"event_location_key\":\"be6d4fb4-c0e3-4303-b70d-7a22b721aa56\",\"event_location_name\":\"Store1\",\"event_location_city\":\"Pittsburgh\",\"event_location_state\":\"PA\",\"event_location_country\":\"US\",\"event_location_lat\":\"\",\"event_location_long\":\"\",\"event_description\":\"\",\"event_acknowledged\":\"False\"}]"

I already have a class with all of the element

Comment: With the Razor view engine or what?

Comment: if you know razor.. im pretty sure it can lead me to the right way

Comment: Yusuf, do you want to display your events in a table, where each event detail will show up? if yes, do you use razor views in mvc ?

Comment: I'm not going to write it for you, but [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908095/help-with-razor-for-a-beginning-programmer) should help you.

Comment: ElYusubov  .yeah i want to display it in  a table it will show up on the view page..i don't use razor view...but if u could u try to help me using razor and i can figure it out..im using aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use following code (in aspx view engine). ViewModel below should have a EventList, which is essentially your collection of events:

```
<table id="domainlist" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Year
            </th>
             <th>
                Program
            </th>                
            <th>
                Min Score
            </th>           
            <th>
                Max Score
            </th>
             <th>
               Action
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% foreach (var item in Model.EventList)
       { %>        
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: item.FiscalYear%>
            </td>
            <td>
                  <%: item.ProgramTypeDescription%>
            </td>               
            <td>
                <%: item.MinScore%>
            </td>           
            <td>
                <%: item.MaxScore%>
            </td> 
            <td>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("View", "ViewProgram", "Program", new { programId = item.Id })%>
            </td>                    
        </tr>        
    <% } %>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```